# XML to PHP variable then to Flashvars

Tags: php, xml, flashvars

Is it possible to use php to read an XML file and then pass that data to Flashvars?

Upon searching for a solution I can only find how to point the XML to a file. Currently I am opening the XML file, assigning it to a PHP variable, adjusting it and then writing it to a file which is then picked up by Flashvars. This works 99% of the time, but sometimes the results are totally wrong! I cannot with my current knowledge debug this problem.

It would be so much easier if I could just pass the data as a string instead of a file.

Here is my current PHP code...

```
    <?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('content.xml');

    // Search and replace text in $homepage

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, '');
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $homepage);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.pathToXML = "testFile.txt";
        var params = {wmode: "transparent"};
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("flashfile.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "660", "120", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

And here is my XML...

```
    <root>
        <config>
            <columns>6</columns>
            <padding>8</padding>
            <horizontal_align>true</horizontal_align>
            <vertical_align>true</vertical_align>
            <scale>0.7</scale>
        </config>

        <loop>
            <title>6th (bottom)</title>
            <path>sounds/string6</path>
            <key>name6</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>
        <loop>
            <title>5th</title>
            <path>sounds/string5</path>
            <key>name5</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>
        <loop>
            <title>4th</title>
            <path>sounds/string4</path>
            <key>name4</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>
        <loop>
            <title>3rd</title>
            <path>sounds/string3</path>
            <key>name3</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>
        <loop>
            <title>2nd</title>
            <path>sounds/string2</path>
            <key>name2</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>
        <loop>
            <title>1st (top)</title>
            <path>sounds/string1</path>
            <key>name1</key>
            <volume>0.6</volume>
            <panning>0</panning>
            <offset>0</offset>
        </loop>     
    </root>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're saving it to a file at all?  Why not just assign the data to flashvars directly in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: The only reason I do it this way is because its the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: How would I get the XML data from the PHP variable into flashvars without saving to a file?

Comment: Great time to learn a new way to do it, then!  How about you simply add values to the flashvars object you created?  `var flashvars = {somethingImportant: "some important string I need to pass to my flash!", anotherVar: "Yet more data for my flash"};`

Comment: So I can put XML in there for flash?? Or do I need to break the XML down to separate Vars? I'll post my XML to the question now.

Comment: Ah, that you can't pass along, to my knowledge.  Have you considered using a dynamic page instead of an actual XML file?  You can, for example, set `flashvars.pathToXml = "/dynamicXml.php"`.  Inside dynamicXml.php you would output XML headers (`header("Content-Type:text/xml");`) and the XML string instead of writing a file.  Writing to the disk is expensive in terms of time.

Comment: I have tried dynamic XML, but I could not pass variables into it with out writing it to disc and then reading it. My need for this process seems to out weigh my capabilities to understand and execute it.

Comment: DomDocument and SimpleXML may be two PHP classes you'll want to look into.  DomDocument can be very daunting but is the best way to **edit** XML.  SimpleXML is a great way to **read** and **write/output** XML.

Answer (score 0):

i made something similar a while ago. hope it can help you.

```
 <?php


    function extractXML($url){
      $doc = new DOMDocument();
      $doc->load($url);
      $arrFeeds = array();
      foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('loop') as $node) {
        $itemRSS = array ( 
          'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'path' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'key' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'volume' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'panning' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'offset' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue
          );
        array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
      }
        return $arrFeeds;
    }


    $tabXmlData = extractXML("YOURLINK");


    for($i = 0; $i < (int)$feedAmount; $i++){
        if(isset($tabXmlData[$i])){
            $flashVars .= "INSERT WHAT NEEDED";
        }
    }


    ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {<?php echo $flashVars ?>};
    flashvars.pathToXML = "testFile.txt";
    var params = {wmode: "transparent"};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("flashfile.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "660", "120", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Clarifications : 
the function is basically storing your XML in an array with associative keys. all you need to do after that is take the params you want and store them in the correct format for flashvars.

PS: if you need to replace strings value go check `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`

Comment: Wow Thank you very much! Though I am a little confused at what goes where you wrote   "INSERT WHAT NEEDED";

I wanted to search and replace the whole XML file to replace the occurrences of string6 to 1 and name6 to 1. Is that where I do my searching and replacing?

Comment: Now I am totally confused. It may be way over my head. I know how to use str_replace() but how to use it in that function to replace 12 stings I have no idea. If I am using `var flashvars = {<?php echo $flashVars ?>};` Do I need `flashvars.pathToXML = "testFile.txt";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

Download xml2array, very helpful in all php / xml apps http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

Include it on your page.

Then use the following lines:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('content.xml');

$xml_array = xml2array($homepage);
```

You can do as few things if you want: either use explode() to make it a string like you had said, you can json_encode() the array and then echo that out in your Javascript block, or just output the code on the page like so:

```
param.something = <?= $xml_array['my_key']; ?>;
```